# Angular How to get All Images

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function that stores image data, such as the name. Through a * ngFor I can load this data are in the database and present in boxes.

**Html**

```
<div class="row tab-pane Galeria">
        <div *ngFor="let product of products" (click)="ImageInfo($event,product.id)" class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <div class="image-item">
            <a class="d-block image-block h-100" >
              <img [src]="Imagenss"  class="Images img-fluid" alt="">
              <div class="ImageText"> {{product.name}}</div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Picture 1**

Here are the saved data of each image in the database.

[image: Image1]

Through (click) on the box image, it returns me its ID and I execute a get to go to the folder to get the image that has the same ID.

How can I do this without using click and all images are loaded without having to click one by one to perform the function?

**GetImage Function**

```
ImageInfo(e, id) {
    if (e != null) {
      this.ID = id;
    }
    let self = this;
      self.homeService.getImage(self.ID).then(function (resultado) {
        if (resultado) {
          self.Imagenss = resultado;
        }
      }).catch();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

as I understood you, you want to display images right away without doing any logic?

Try to get all image URLs after you receive products.

For example, move this to the separated component:

```
<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <div class="image-item">
    <a class="d-block image-block h-100" >
      <img [src]="Imagenss"  class="Images img-fluid" alt="">
        <div class="ImageText"> {{product.name}}</div>
     </a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

and inside that child component something like this:

```
@Input() product: TypeOfProduct
 ngOnInit() {
   this.homeService.getImage(this.product.ID).then((resultado) => {
    if (resultado) {
      this.imagenss = resultado;
    }
  }).catch();
 }
```

then, from parent component just pass product as input, for example:

```
<div class="row tab-pane Galeria">
 <example-component *ngFor="let product of products" [product]="product"><example-component>
</div>
```

Comment: The answer is more a like as comments. so please put it in comments,.

Comment: Sure, I plan to get all image urls, but how can I do that? The goal is to have a function that loads all images, without clicks, according to the id I get from the products.

Comment: I am trying understand your scenario. Please correct me if i am wrong. You are now clicking on a particular product and showing the list of images associated to the specific product. And now you want it to be displayed without clicking ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many images you have to load. if there are millions of images in the database to display, it was not possible to load all images initially . it was better use lazy loading.  in Java script , you can use Intersection observer to handle loading process

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#A_simple_example